# Images not resizing automatically (via CSS) in Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, resize, image-resizing

I have these images in my webpage, that I want to automatically shrink when the viewport's width is reduced. I am using the following CSS to do this:

```
.autoResizeImage {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

The images which I want to resize are of two types:

1. Ones which are inside `td`'s in a `table`
2. Ones which are not inside a `table`

On Chrome, images of both types shrink automatically when the viewport's width is reduced. However, on Firefox and Internet Explorer at least, this shrinking is only happening for the second type, and not for the first type (a scrollbar appears instead).

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadka/raSSq/2/

Notice that the small cell contained images do NOT resize in Firefox/IE, however the banner at the bottom DOES resize.

Can someone figure out what the issue is ?

Comment: Is the .autoResizeImage an <img>?
Also the height and width: auto is irrelevant. Max-width also only works if all parent tags have a set width too. (So not width auto anywhere in the parent tags)

Comment: autoResizeImage is a CSS rule, which is being used in the images ..

Comment: I know but to what tag is it applied? An image tag? Because you can also set background image etc trough CSS on a regular div etc.

Comment: Its being used like this: `<img class="autoResizeImage" src".....">`

Comment: Yeah sorry didn't notice the fiddle. Also for me it's working fine on Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things:

1. width:auto; will tend to make the image use its actual width, rather than stretching to fit a larger area. You should use width:100%;
2. Once your images are set to use 100% of the available area you also need to set your table to use 100% of the available area via width:100%;

Result:

```
.autoResizeImage {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.imageTable table {
    width:100%;
}
```

This seems to work as a basic solution for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/5AYWd/1/

Also, if you want the images to stop growing at a certain point, that is when you'd use max-width. You might want to set a max-width on the table as well.

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5AYWd/2).

Comment: Uh, I actually just want the images to shrink, not expand .. And also only shrink when the available parent width is lesser. When the parent width is more than needed, their maximum size should not exceed their actual size .. In your solutions, images seem to grow beyond their actual size too, which is not what I want ..

Comment: If you just set the max-width to be the actual size then they will stop growing when they get that big - similar to the second example. I'm afraid you'll have to do that separately for each image if they all have different widths. Although you could use a media query to specify that width:100% only kicks in when the screen size is lower than a certain size.